# Metric balls in Teichmüller space are topological balls

Tags: riemann-surfaces, teichmuller-theory, conformal-geometry, quasiconformal

Let $X$ be a topological surface of finite type and $\mathcal{T}_X$ be the corresponding Teichmüller space. Let $B$ be a ball with respect to the Teichmüller metric on $\mathcal{T}_X$ (i.e., the metric defined as the logarithm of minimal quasiconformal dilatation). Could you provide a reference for the fact that $B$ is a topological ball, i.e., it is homeomorphic to a unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Doesn’t this follow immediately from the fact that there are unique geodesics between any two points and that geodesics can be continued infinitely?

Comment: Teichmuller map plays the role of exponential map in Riemannian geometry, and the space of holomorphic quadratic differentials plays the role of tangent space (or cotangent space).  A Teichmuller geodesic ball is homeomorphic to a geodesic ball in the space of holomorphic quadratic differentials, which is necessarily a Euclidean ball.